# can we include maven pmd plugin execution within build goal?

Tags: maven-2, pmd

Guys, I wanted generate the pmd report while building the project so I have added plugin to build section of my pom.xml but still it don't execute until I explicitly call mvn clean install pmd:pmd. I want to execute it with mvn clean install itself. is it possible ? my pom entries are as under:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <targetJdk>${compile.source}</targetJdk>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>./current.pmd.rules.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com/cm/**/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>com/sm/**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hm sorry guys, its just a small mistake I have made while writing the configuration. The `<executions> [...] </executions>` should be out of `<configuration>[...]</configuration>` tag. Since the plugin is intelligent enough to execute it in `verify` phase, we need not to associate it to any phase. We just need to include it in `<build>`section of your pom.xml.

Answer (score 4):

You can associate the pmd goals with `install` phase by modifying your pom to contain the following snippet:

```
<executions>
 <execution>
  <phase>install</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>check</goal>
   <goal>cpd-check</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

But you should associate it with a phase earlier than `install` - like `verify` - so that the checking happens before the `install` phase.

Comment: I'd go with process-classes , but verify is fine, too

Comment: thanks abhin4v but I have attached <phase>install</phase> to that plugin. But still no luck!